My laptop seems to be stuck in a low power mode
My asus vivobook was asleep. I tried to wake it up but before anything appeared on the screen I changed my mind and started to hard shut it off. While I was holding the power button I noticed the critical low power light had turned on, possibly before I touched the power button. That made it seem like it was trying to hibernate. Since then every time it is unplugged it is very slow.
Things I've tried in the order I've tried them:
Restart
Shutdown and turn back on
Boot into linux (using pre-installed refind and arch) - no change. Even with only the CLI running it was slow
Change various sleep and MyASUS (proprietary, windows-based pc management software) while restarting in between changes
I looked in ASUS's UEFI and didn't see much. I did try a couple of their check hardware tests.
Reinstall windows from local drive while keeping my files
Enable hibernate in control panel and manually put my laptop into hibernate mode and wake it back up
Same with sleep
Changed the minimum processor state on battery from 5% to 80% in contol panel - This did help a little which leads me to believe other components are stuck in a low power state
I'm not sure what to try next.

You are very lucky. Its only your laptop that is slow at certain stages. Holding the powerbutton to turn the laptop off at the wrong time could have made windows not startup anymore. You really should not use the hold powerbutton to turn off unless the device is not responding to anything else after at least 1 minute in that state.

Like Lpchip said, do not hard shut off computer like that, you increase the chance of destroying the OS inside, I read you had an linux, try to repair the corrupted file: https://linuxhandbook.com/fsck-command/

You may need to reset the battery charge state in API -- a nuisance. Look online for the method, e.g., https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/for-asus-laptop-users-how-to-reset-your-battery/5084feee-8a17-4b70-9e4c-61ca71c0757c and https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/asus-laptop-battery-bms-reset-ti-bq30z55/
